# Is it good practice to use IServiceCollection in Unity from a HostBuilder?

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine

I am setting up DI in Unity. A lot of the Nuget packages I have are designed to work with IServiceCollection, such as MediatR, so I can simply make one with a HostBuilder. Everything works fine. Any reason why this would be bad or is there a better way?